# DNS lookups timeout for some domains

Tags: networking, dns

From my clients on my network certain DNS requests timeout.

Example: google.com will resolve, but YouTube will timeout

My default gateway is my router, but even when using nslookup (windows) using 8.8.8.8 the timeout will occur for YouTube (google.com resolves)

My router allows for a nslookup through it's web interface, and trying domains that don't resolve locally, do resolve without a problem.

I don't understand what's wrong, my initial thought was a recent firmware update on my router was the problem, but a rollback to older versions didn't really change anything.

I also don't understand when overriding the DNS server using nslookup on a client results in the same timeout behavior (leading me to think there's a problem with forwarding on the router)

Question: what is going on, and what can I do to fix my DNS resolution? And what are good steps to troubleshoot. I've tested traceroute and tracert (windows) to the 8.8.8.8 server and it works, also pinging that DNS server works fine

Edit here are some examples of dig for a domain that does and doesn't resolve:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.7-Ubuntu <<>> r1---sn-ogueln76.googlevideo.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

For a domain that does resolve:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.7-Ubuntu <<>> developers.facebook.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 50712
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;developers.facebook.com.       IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
developers.facebook.com. 3322   IN      CNAME   developers.c10r.facebook.com.
developers.c10r.facebook.com. 8 IN      A       31.13.82.1

;; Query time: 4 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.50.1#53(192.168.50.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Nov 25 07:26:47 JST 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 98
```

Comment: Does the router have a 'packet capture' tool such as tcpdump? (For checking whether the requests arrive at the router and are forwarded.) Does it have any content filtering or 'parental control' features which could block sites?

Comment: @grawity the router does have parental controls, but they are switched off at the moment, as far as I know I don't have lower level access to the router that allows me to tcpdump. Router make/type: Asus RT-ACRH13. I can view logs, but they don't show me this level of detail. Netstat is available on the router and it shows it's listening on :53

Comment: Neither `traceroute` nor `ping` are DNS troubleshooting tools. You should use `dig` or at least `nslookup`. Post traces (commands + replies) of your attemps. Play with the `+tcp` flag to force TCP and `+bufsize`

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I've updated the question with 2 examples of dig - 1 for a domain that does not resolve and one for a domain that does resolve. Hope this gives you more insight in what's wrong - the result 'no servers could be reached' seems odd when other domain can be resolved. I've also contacted tech support of my router to see if they can come up with anything